# Include only one property, not entire database row

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Model:

```
public class Word
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WhenCreated { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string AuthorName
    {
        get
        {
            if (Author != null)
            {
                return Author.UserName;
            }
            else {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Definition> Definitions { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Word> Get()
    {
        return _db.Words.Include(x=>x.Author).ToList();
    }
```

My Controller now returns entire `ApplicationUser` class which is one of properties of `Word`. I want to send only one property of `ApplicationUser`: `UserName`. How can I do that?

I've added `AuthorName`, which would return only data that I want from `ApplicationUser`. Unfortunately I still have to `.Include(x=>x.Author)` to make this property work. Can I somehow omit including `Author` in process of data serialization (to hide it when sending data to user)?

I know I can use `.Select()` method, but it requires me to type all properties I will need. If I modify my Model in the future, I will need to update all those `.Select()` which will would be inconvenient and waste of time.

How would you solve that?

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a Dto object and assign the values to it and return the Dto instead.

Dto

```
public class WordDto 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WhenCreated { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your action

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<WordDto>> Get()
{
    return _db.Words
              .Include(x=>x.Author)
              .Select(x =>
                  new WordDto 
                  {
                      Title = x.Title,
                      DateTime = x.WhenCreated,
                      AuthorName = x.Author?.UserName ?? string.Empty
                  }
              )
              .ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: I would remove `.ToList()`, it feels more correct, let the controller materialize the query when it requires it

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand it. Using Select that way will return only some `UserName` variable (i'm not sure what it is, it's not present in `Word` class). I want to return all properties of `Word` class and one of properties of `Author`

Comment: Then you need to create a Dto object and do the assignment/flatten to it

Comment: Which is what I didn't want to do, because every little change in main model will require changes in all places that I use it with `.Select()`. It of course solves that problem, but I see this as temporary solution.

Comment: You should never return persistence models from REST services, the consequences of a db Change is far worse than having to update models: All applications which consume this RESTapi will need to be updated with every change to the persistence. This is way worse. That's why you abstract the data access layer into repositories or request handlers

Comment: You don't need a DTO if you simply return `Task<IActionResult>` and wrap a projected anonymous type in `return Ok(data);`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try it as shown below.

**Note :** You don't need to use `Include` here.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Word>> Get()
    {
        return _db.Words.Select(x => new  
                      {
                          Word = x,
                          AuthorName = x.Author.UserName
                      }
                  ).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it shows an error: "Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access"

Comment: How can you do `x.Author.Select(y => new { y.UserName })` when the `Author` property is not an `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Oh..Corrected. Thanks @Brad

Comment: You'll find in EF Core that you do need to do an `Include(x => x.Author)` or else the `Author` property will be null.

Comment: This doesn't compile in any way, you cannot implicitly convert an anonymous type to a class

Answer (score 2):

Create a View model and use AutoMapper to populate. Look at using AutoMapper and ProjectTo extension https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

That way if you add properties to View model they will be automatically mapped if they exist on your EF model

So create a VM with required properties named appropriately (see AutoMapper docs on naming conventions):

```
public class WordVM 
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime? WhenCreated { get; set; }
    public string AuthorUserName { get; set; }
}
```

Then use AutoMapper to project (it will do any required includes so if you changed the VM later then it would handle that)

```
  _db.Words.ProjectTo<WordVM>().ToList();
```

You don't need the `NotMapped` property AutoMapper would map the navigation property `Author` and the Author Property `UserName` to `AuthorUserName`

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was to get all the related entities with .include(), then loop over them and omit the property values I did not want to return. It would require some maintenance in case your model changed, but surprisingly, it did not impact the response time dramatically.